# iPhone 11 Pro - repeatedly being asked to enter passcode to continue using iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, password

I recently changed the passcode on  my iPhone 11 Pro.  About a day after, I started receiving messages saying:

“Confirm iPhone Passcode - Confirm your iPhone passcode to keep using iCloud.  You recently changed this passcode you use to unlock this iPhone.  This passcode also protects access to data stored in iCloud.”

Is this legit?  I’ve changed passcodes several times in the past and never encountered this. Wouldn’t Apple program it so that when you change passcodes, it does so for all services? I searched for this issue on a few sites but haven’t found an answer.

Comment: Do you usually backup your iPhone on iCloud? If so, can you do a backup?

Comment: Yes, I do back up and to iCloud and with the most recent one taking place yesterday.  A back up also took place a day before the afore mentioned issue began to occur.